# how to disable ng-click event in confirmation Popup Button

Tags: html, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

How to disable ng-click event in  confirmation Popup Button 
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txxke.png)[Screen-Shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a direcftive like this one :

```
app.directive('ngConfirmClick', [
function(){
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            var msg = attr.ngConfirmClick || "Are you sure?";
            var clickAction = attr.confirmedClick;
            element.bind('click',function (event) {
                if ( window.confirm(msg) ) {
                    scope.$apply(clickAction);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

You use it this way :

```
<button confirmed-click="YourFunction()" ng-confirm-click="Are you really sure you want to do this ?">Action</button>
```

Comment: @RaviShah Please upvote/accept the answer if it works for you :)

Comment: ya sure.. but i m new in stack flow.. so this is my first question so, can't accept in stack flow due to some reputation..